# Basic ORM strategy in PHP: How could it look like?

Tags: php, architecture, orm

Basic ORM strategy in PHP: How could it look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without wishing to cause offense, I’d suggest that you scale this back quite a bit - you seem to be biting off a lot more than you can chew considering your familiarly with the language and general OO practices. (I'm basing this on some other questions you've asked - not just this one.)

As an general suggestion, I think you'd save yourself a lot of pain by having a thorough read up on object orientation in general (design patterns couldn't hurt as well) and then thinking about the problem afresh.

Alternatively, if you post the problem you’re trying to solve (rather than discussing issues with a solution you’ve decided upon) you might get more traction.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at existing PHP ORMs for an example:

- [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/)
- [Propel](http://propel.phpdb.org/trac/)
- [Outlet](http://outlet-orm.org/)
- [Sprig](http://github.com/shadowhand/sprig) (Currently in development by the author of the Kohana framework)

Those are the main ORMs people use, listed in order of popularity.